# How to clear dalvik cache if DDMS doesn't recognize device?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cache, dalvik

I have a Navon Platinum Explorer tablet (wich is not an original Navon tablet). Few years ago I was able to clear the dalvik cache, with DDMS in Eclipse (Mars) but it's full again and DDMS doesn't recognize the device, so I can't clear it. Windows  says unknown device. I looked for this device in Oracle VM USB device list and there I found it as **Onda (unverified) V972 tablet in flashing mode**.
When I turn the tablet on it display the android logo and stuck there. When I press the <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>Volume up</kbd> / <kbd>Volume down</kbd> buttons it doesn't display anything, but connects to the PC (or if already connected then disconnects). I can't enter recovery menu.
So how can I clear the dalvik cache, and disable logging so it doesn't get full again?

### From Ubuntu

*(First, I do not really know linux yet.)*
With `sudo lshw -short` command I get some interesting item related to the device (with H/W path /0/100/6/*):
[image]
It's maybe possible to do something whith it?

Comment: Is the device rooted?

Comment: @BoLawson I don't rooted this device, but the previous owner maybe.

Comment: I guess the first thing to address would be getting the device recognized by the computer. Try `updating the drivers` next thing would be try switching between `mtp` and `ptp` in settings to see if eclipse can recognize the device. What version of windows are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro 64 bit, and see the edit.

Comment: Flashing mode should be the bootloader but I do not know if it uses fastboot commands. Not much can be done to the davlik-cache since it resides in /data/dalvik-cache. However it might be possible to erase the cache which is different. So do you have `adb` and `fastboot` installed on your computer? For adb is `usb debugging` turned on through developer settings? On a side not I am not sure the device is visible to eclipse while in the bootloader. I believe you need to be in the android os or recovery.

Comment: I don't know (or remembered) that the usb debugging is was enabled. Where should I install adb and fastboot on the Windows OS (host) or on Ubuntu (guest)?

Comment: What ever you are most comfortable with. **The `usb debugging` is important. It can very much so make your device invisible to eclipse and the computer itself.** Check to see if `Developer settings` is visible. If not go to `Settings/about device/software-possibly/tap the build number 7 times to enable developer settings. Exit it out to Settings menu go to developer settings scroll down to `use debugging` press it to toggle it on. Then restart eclipse and try to see if device is now shown. before you try to get adb installed. https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87383/discussion-between-noel-nemeth-and-bo-lawson).